# Using Java keystore in PHP

Tags: java, php, porting, keystore

I'm looking to port a small Java security library to PHP.  The Java implementation makes use of a keystore for signing some stuff and I'm wondering how to go about recreating this functionality in PHP.  Of course the original Java implementation must still work with the same key pair/keystore.

I have very little experience with PHP and havn't tried to do anything portable with Java keystores before.

I expect there is some way to export the private key to a format that can be used by PHP.

Does anyone know exactly what I need to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't absolutely set on porting your code to php, you can use the [php-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) to make calls to it from php. If your java code is proven, there's no reason to discard it out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

http://phpkeystore.org/ may be of use.

**EDIT:** As implied by Mihir below, that site appears to be gone. 
The last "good" archive of it is available at https://web.archive.org/web/20170607151254/http://phpkeystore.org/

Comment: Is it no longer available?

Comment: Hi Mihir, please see my edit above - it seems the main website is gone, so I've found and linked to the archived copy.